# Profile: Consecutive days not working correctly

Tags: bug, status-completed, consecutive-days, visited-days

I didn't found exactly that problem:

In my profile, it is stated that i'm member for 54 days, but nevertheless is also says that i visited SO for 59 consecutive days. How comes?

Comment: Possibly related to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54681/inconsistent-consecutive-days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of bugs in these site visit counters - [they've been ironed out now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54681/inconsistent-consecutive-days/55688#55688) (hopefully :).