# StackOverflow shows "32 consecutive" days; Where's my "Enthusiast" badge?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, activity-badges

Hi, [my SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/331508/brock-adams) shows that I've visited for "32 consecutive" days -- which should be roughly right.

Yet I don't have the highly coveted, "Enthusiast" badge.  Why not?

Comment: FANATIC.  Now there's highly coveted.

Comment: Mine shows 397, where's my "get a life" badge?

Comment: @tvanfosson - did I miss a day? I'm only on 396... seems unlikely that I'd miss *exactly* the day they started logging this.. bizarre.

Comment: @Marc - maybe that can be your first bug fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My profile says 35 days consecutive. The thing is I [**know**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54681/inconsistent-consecutive-days/54793#54793) that its wrong and that if my calculations are correct I should either get the Enthusiast badge on day 36 or 37. Just be a bit patient and you will have it soon enough.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not crushed about missing the badge (well not much), but this is obviously a bug, as that related link shows.

Comment: @Brock, Like I said, be patient and you will get your Enthusiast badge soon. I am on 36 consecutive days now and just got my badge. Woohoo!! :)

Comment: So I will also wait a little bit in this case. Because I had similar problem like Brock Adams.

Answer (score 4):

There were a couple of bugs in these site visit counters - [they've been ironed out now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54681/inconsistent-consecutive-days/55688#55688) (hopefully :).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, Pieter van Niekerk, et al.

The answer seems to be that the *consecutive days* display is wrong and that the badge-award *seems* to run off a different calculation (in violation of [DRY principles](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself))?

So this might be 2 bugs for the price of one?

Answer (score 1):

There are [known issues with the consecutive day count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54681/inconsistent-consecutive-days) as reported in the profile. Sit tight and it will be corrected, and you'll get the Enthusiast badge when it's really time.

Comment: I wonder if this is fixed now. For meta I earned the enthusiast badge 14 days ago and my profile says *"44 consecutive"*.

Comment: @Andy E's head, Nope it's not fixed.  I'm at 33 days and no badge.

Comment: @Brock Adams: weird how it's fine for some but not others.