# I'm not getting badges

Tags: support, badges, user-accounts

My Stack Overflow account has stopped receiving badges, although there are a couple I'm eligible for, e.g. [Enthusiast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/39/enthusiast). What's going on?

Comment: Which ones do you not have that you believe you've qualified for?  Some badges only appear every few days, because constant monitoring would be too expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest test you can do is to earn yourself the Autobiographer badge on SO. Enter any information in the fields you have not, and give it a few days. The longest wait time for badges, normally, [is 2 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49727/is-there-a-bug-in-epic-badge-calculation-are-they-handed-out-daily/49735#49735), so after 2 days if you have not yet received the Autobiographer badge, then it would be wise to investigate this further.

By the way, if the badge itself is one of the Enthusiast/Fanatic badges and you're measuring your eligibility solely on your profile's listed consecutive day count, [be aware that there is currently a display error with the consecutive count which may show more days than actually are recorded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55150/stackoverflow-shows-32-consecutive-days-wheres-my-enthusiast-badge).

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/reputation for more detailed data.

Answer (score 1):

If you got a badge in the past, and the post that got you that badge got deleted or migrated, you retain the badge, but the next one that you should get counts as the one you already have, and that's why you don't get it again.

The badge assigner checks how many badges you should have, how many you have, and assigns you what you're missing.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Just the fact that you don't have any badges here after posting a question here on meta is a good showcase of the bug</strike>

Ah nevermind, you just got a meta badge.

The problem you are probably seeing is that certain badge calculations are only run every once in a while(like every week or so). Just be patient. If you have not gotten the badge by next week then come and post here again..

Comment: He/she has been registered on Meta for less than 10 minutes. lol

Comment: @Jon still you always get a badge quite quickly for the first question badge and first upvote and all that crap

Comment: @Jon also, they should have gotten the autobiographer badge immediately from the copied profile information.

Comment: Just got Student; Autobiographer is ineligible as the Age field is empty.

Comment: In addition to Jon's comment, OP was asking about SO, not Meta; _could_ be a separate issue.  Also it took me I think two days to get Autobiographer.