# How did my consecutive day count jump from 21 to 12?

Tags: bug, consecutive-days

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inconsistent consecutive days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54681/inconsistent-consecutive-days)

Last night my account said "21 consecutive" This morning my account says "12 consecutive"

What's up with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original consecutive day count was likely to be erroneous, as described in the bug report [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54681/inconsistent-consecutive-days). Consequently, said bug report has been fixed, so people's consecutive day counts should be more accurate now. Since your count dropped to a number besides 1, it can be concluded that yours was one of the many accounts that were affected by the original bug, so the 12 is actually the correct number.